# How to find all files sourcing a particular file?

Tags: r

Suppose I have `file_a.R`.  It is sourced via R's base source function by some other files `file_b.R`, `file_c.R`, which are located in the same folder or sub folder.  Is there an easy way to get the paths of `file_b.R` and `file_c.R` given the path of `file_a.R`?

Comment: You could search for any file that contains the text `source("file_a.R")` or something like that. But there isn't any stronger connection between those files. Or maybe just grep for `source(` because you may build the path dynamically or something. If you are in a situation like this, it sounds like you should look into creating a package rather than sourcing files.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond MrFlick.Checking all files is indeed an option, although a bit costly. I guess I was hoping that sourcing indeed connects the files in an exploitable way. I agree that the situation I am asking about comes up more often when the number of files is high so switching to package makes sense.

Comment: In your favourite IDE, do a search in files for "file_a.R"

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If you want to get all links between R files, and some files that are sourced in those files, you can use something like that:

```
library(stringr)

#Get all R files paths in working directory and subdirectories
filelist <- lapply(list.files(
    pattern = "[.]R$", recursive = TRUE
  ), print)

#Extract one file's sources
getSources <- function(file, pattern) {

#Store all file lines in a character vector
  lines <- readLines(file, warn = FALSE)

#Extract R-filenames starting with "pattern" in all lines containing "source"
  sources <- lapply(lines, function(x) {

    if (length(grep("source", x) > 0)) {
          str_extract(x, paste0(pattern, ".*[.]R"))
    }
    else{
      NA
    }
  })

#Remove NA (lines without source)
  sources <- sources[!is.na(sources)]

#Return a list
  list(path = file,
       pattern = pattern,
       sources = unlist(sources))

}

#Example
corresp <- lapply(X = filelist, FUN = getSources, pattern = "file")
```

It will return a list of:

```
$path: R file path
$pattern: pattern used to match sources
$sources: the name of the sourced file
```

And you'll be able to see if anything is sourced anywhere, including file_A.

Comment: Thanks for your response as well Kevin. Unfortunately, the code you provided allows to search for patterns in file names and not the files themselves, if I am not mistaken. My goal however is to find file names of the files including a given path / pattern.

Comment: Ok I think it's more clear :), I changed a few things and I hope it will help you build your solution.

Comment: This can get messy if you pass parameters to `source()` like `f<-"myfile.R"; source(f)` or if you build filenames dynamically like `source(paste0("file",i,".R")`. Evaluation is required to be certain what file the function will be opening.

Comment: Hmmm I understand, so you can refine this idea of text mining sources as much as you want, it will always be either pretty complicated or unstable.